# WooRank Touchscreen Readiness Failing

Tags: responsive-design, seo, responsiveness

I'm currently using the WooRank website to improve my sites SEO>

However, it keeps failing on "Touchscreen Readiness". It states my buttons should be 40px in height/width which they appear to be.. but it's failing.

Any advice?
URL:
http://www.answer-hut.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually says 48px. Check your search console (formerly Google Webmaster Tools) under 'Search Traffic' > 'Mobile Usability' to see if any issues are showing up in there. You can drill down to see specific pages that are flagged as having issues.